# converting from MySQL to MySQLi Object-oriented

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

Ok, so I've been informed that it would be best practice to convert over to the new mysqli
So I've been working on this on a new site, so far so good, but I ran into a problem where I can't figure out how to convert it for my search query

I have a search feature added to my site, but now I can't get it to work.

This was my old code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM snippet_tools WHERE `db_title` LIKE ".sql_val('%'.$_GET['search'].'%')." OR `db_body`=".sql_val('%'.$_GET['search'].'%');
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("<b>A fatal MySQL error occured</b>.<br />Query: ".$query."<br />Error: (".mysql_errno().") ".mysql_error());

$anymatches = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($anymatches == 0 ) {
```

I've upgraded my code to user oo

this is what I have:

```
$servername = "localhost"; $username = "xxxxxxxxx"; $password = "xxxxxxxxx"; $dbname = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
// Create connection 
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); 
// Check connection 
if ($conn->connect_error) { 
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); 
}

$sql_search = "SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE `q_title` LIKE ".sql_val('%'.$_GET['search'].'%')." OR `q_answered` LIKE ".sql_val('%'.$_GET['search'].'%');
$result = $conn->query($sql_search);

$anymatches = $result->num_rows;

if ($anymatches == 0 ) {
```

but every time I run it to perform a search I keep getting this error message:

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in H:\root\site5\questions.php on line 611

Comment: if the `line 611` is referring to `$result = $conn->query($sql_search);` .  How did you build `$conn` object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to get property of non-object MySQLi result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332842/trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-mysqli-result)

Comment: could you show were you create your connection (`$conn`)?

Comment: First off, which line is like `611`? Second, where do you define `$conn`?

Comment: It would really help if you would tell us what line 611 is.

Comment: I'm calling it from another file called config.php  

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxxxxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

Comment: time to ditch out that `sql_val` function and move to prepared statements instead

Comment: @TrevTech Still doesn't answer which line 611 is.

Comment: Add the statement `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your file, run the program, then check your `error.log` and tell us exactly which line of code is failing.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer W3 School site and get basic idea about the variations of MySQL and MySQLi  and their functions. It is really helpful to go ahead with your project.

Ex  [Database connection example in both ways](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp)

So you can solve your problem based on that concept. Try to extract concepts.

Comment: Thanks, it turns out that I had an error on my connection string, once I've fixed this, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach!

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $servername = "localhost"; $username = "root"; $password = "root"; $dbname = "cities"; 
    // Create connection 
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); 
    // Check connection 
    if ($conn->connect_error) { 
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); 
    }

    $get = array('search' => "Lon");

    $sql_search = "SELECT * FROM cities WHERE (city_name LIKE '%$get[search]%')";

    $result = $conn->query($sql_search);

    $anymatches = $result->num_rows;

    if ($anymatches == 0 ){
        echo "No matches!";
    }
    else
    {
        echo $anymatches . " match found!";
    }

?>
```

[image: Screenshot of my database]

---

[image: Screenshot of the result]